# Detecting click/touchscreen input on a 3d object inside godot

Tags: godot

I am trying my best to build a mobile game in the godot game engine. And i have run into a problem. In a 3D game, how can i detect a mouse click on a specific object or rather where that object is on the screen. I do not understand how to use the control nodes in order to to this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make a 3D object clickable is to give it a `CollisionObject` (such as a `StaticBody`) and connect to the [`input_event`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_collisionobject.html#signals) signal. For example, to detect a left-click:

```
extends StaticBody

func _ready():
    connect("input_event", self, "on_input_event")

func on_input_event(camera, event, click_position, click_normal, shape_idx):
    var mouse_click = event as InputEventMouseButton
    if mouse_click and mouse_click.button_index == 1 and mouse_click.pressed:
        print("clicked")
```

The [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/inputs/input_examples.html#touch-events) mention that touch events are similar to click events.

Note that `input_ray_pickable` must be `true` on the `CollisionObject` (this is the default).

Comment: does it actually matter where the collision object is, or just that its a child of the 3DArea?

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 an `Area` _is_ a `CollisionObject`. The `Area` itself will emit an `input_event` signal which you can handle.

Comment: I'd read [elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/7xwr22/guide_how_to_click_a_sprite/) that this did not apply for 2D `Area`s and required a 2D collision box, I assumed the same applied to 3D, is this not the case? Edit: I've checked, you *have* to add a `CollisionShape` to the 3DArea, or the editor itself complains at you about it having no shape? I'll just stick it into its own scene with everything stuck in 0,0,0 and instance the scene when I need it, so positions don't matter, it'll all move as one when being used

Comment: Ah, I think we got a little mixed up over the CollisionObject/CollisionShape terminology. Any `CollisionObject` (`Area`, `StaticBody`, ect.) must have one or more `CollisionShapes` in order to detect any collisions.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I've got around this anyway as I said by just having it all in its own scene, but does the position of the `ColShape` matter?

Comment: Yes, the collision shape should be aligned so it matches (roughly) the mesh.